# Configure Splunk for CLI

Tags: splunk

I'd like to configure Splunk from the CLI, so that it has the **same reports** that I set-up manually. If/how can I do this? I know I can do thing like open listener ports, but I can't see if it possible to set-up reports, indexes, etc.

Comment: this question is rather difficult to understand... do you want to retrieve results from the cli?

Comment: No. I want to create "phoenix servers" (Docker containers in fact) with Splunk on them. They should be set-up with the same indexes, reports, etc, so there is no manual set-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure nearly all Splunk server settings from the CLI. Be advised that the common GUI interface (the search head) is simply that, a GUI interface. There are API's to extract data from your indexers in many programming languages see here http://dev.splunk.com/sdks. What you do with that data once you have it is completely customizable from that point.